# how to use multiple middleware with socket using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i have rider and vendor with difference middleware.

```
const { riderMiddware } = require("../services/customer/AuthService");
module.exports = function (io) {
    io.use(riderMiddware )
    //io.use(vendorMiddware )
    // app.set('io', io)`your text`
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        console.log('socket',socket);
        // socket.join(socket.userId)
        socket.on("placeorder", (d) => {
            const response = new Date();
            socket.emit("testing",response)
            // io.to('641bff1c1c52c40b48193586').emit('connected', {data: "blar"})
        });
        const response = "Helloffffff";
        socket.emit("testing",response)
    })
}
```

i need to show alert at vendor portal when rider accepted an order .